# vector constructor creating vector with one less element

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am trying to split a vector into "almost equal" parts, and create subvectors for those parts.

I have asked the original question here: [How to split a vector into n "almost equal" parts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6861089/518169) but I found a really good solution, what I am trying to use, from here: [Best way to extract a subvector from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421573/best-way-to-extract-a-subvector-from-a-vector/421669#421669)

I wrote this function for creating integers for start and end values (round is my function which rounds to specified digits.)

```
void split( double number, double parts )
{
    double loop = number / parts;

    for( int i = 0; i < parts; i++ )
    {
        int start = round( i * loop, 0 );
        int end = round( ( i + 1 ) * loop - 1, 0 );
        cout << start << " " << end << endl;
    }
}
```

This function so far works OK, but my problem is that when I try to run this:

```
vector<some> dest( &source[start], &source[end] );
```

Then it creates one LESS element, then required. I mean for example if I call it with

```
vector<some> dest( &source[0], &source[99] );
```

then it will have 99 elements, instead of 100. **Why is this happening?**

**How can I fix it?** If I use [end+1], then it terminates at the last vector, with "subscript out of range."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vector` constructor (and all STL constructors that accept pointer ranges, for that matter) are designed to take in a range of STL-style iterators.  When using iterators, you specify a range by providing a pointer to the first- and the past-the-end elements, not the first and last elements.  If you wanted to create a `vector` as a copy of the subrange (0, 99) out of another `vector`, you could write

```
vector<some> dest(source.begin(), source.begin() + 100);
```

Note that this uses `vector` iterators to specify the slice of the first 100 elements rather than `operator[]`, which has undefined behavior when the provided index is out of bounds.  In your case, this undefined behavior is manifesting as a runtime debug error.  Iterators don't have this problem, since they're specifically designed to be used this way.

If you want to use raw C++ arrays as input to the `vector` constructor, you could do it like this:

```
vector<some> dest(source, source + 100);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, I understand. So for my function, the proper call is this? vector<some> dest( source.begin() + start, source.begin() + end + 1 );

Comment: Assuming that `end` is the index of the last element that you want, yes, that's correct.  Typically, though, the name `end` is used with respect to C++ containers to indicate one-past-the-end rather than the actual last element, so you might want to rename it to something like `last`.

Comment: Thanks! Its called 'last' now

Answer (score 0):

While it's not legal to use `&v[n]` if v is an `std::vector` with `n` elements you can use instead

```
vector<some> dest(v.begin()+first, v.begin()+last+1);
```

even if `last+1 == n`.